# Sort on numericals giving improper order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Here is my code snippet

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var mylist = [ "20","3","100","50"];
        mylist = mylist.sort();
        $("#mydiv").html(mylist.join(""));
    });
```

Its printing on my div like below

```
100
20
3
50
```

But giving proper order if I am giving data like "twenty","three","hundread","fifty".

```
fifty
hundread
three
twenty
```

Please help,what I am missing??

Thanks.

Comment: How is the sort related to jQuery?

Comment: It's sorting alphabetically. You'll need to pass your own comparison function to sort numerically.

Comment: @Alexander - see that edit link...

Comment: @j08691, sorry, say again? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default compare mathod use alphabetic order. If you want to sort numbers use this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

Comment: The guy who downvoted this forgot to lift his downvote, most likely

Comment: Note that the data passed not being numeric is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts values in alphabetical order by default.
The method can also be used with an optional parameter: a comparaison function

To sort numerical values, use:

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 10, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});

// numbers -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sortnumerically = function(a,b){
    if (a<b) return -1;
    else if (a>b) return 1; 
    else= return 0;
}
var mylist = [ 20,3,100,50];
mylist = mylist.sort(sortnumerically);
$("#mydiv").html(mylist.join(","));
```

okay, to explain the sortnumerically  comparator function. Simply put it accepts two inputs a,b : elements presumably from the array. If ab returns 1 (that's what a comparator is supposed to do).

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmzua/1/

Comment: sortnumerically function can be much simpler.

Comment: a-b, i know. I was trying to explain the concept

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from the array values and use below extra function to get ascending order
Mylist = Mylist.sort (function (a, b){return a-b});

Answer (score -1):

You defined your numbers as string literals thus js sorts them as strings. You need to define then as *number* literals: `[ 20, 3, 100, 50]` for the sort to work as required.

Comment: Passing numbers won't help